# how kubernetes listens ports

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to resolve the local issues of the applicaiton deployed on local microk8s where I have the nginx ingress installed
There are two ingresses:

1. demo.localdev.me
2. localhost

These things are accessible on port 80 and work fine. However, `sudo netstat -tlpnc` and `sudo lsof -i -P` do not show any application listening on port 80.
How it is possible?
Sometime my system responds 'Failed to connect to localhost port 80 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server' and I don't know who to blame, either ingress, or my application

Comment: Network integration usually works via the kernel packet manipulation - which might be provided by iptables, nftables or eBPF depending on the host where the container is running. `iptables -L` is probably a good place to start.

Comment: Does @symcbean comment help you in your concern?